# is there an equivalent of Array#compact for empty elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As we all know, `Array#compact` removes `nil` elements from the array.

`array.reject { |element| element.empty? }`

would remove empty elements like `[]` (in rails you could also do `#blank?` to get rid of empty elements *and* `nil` elements).

Is there a shorthand method for removing empty/blank elements like `Array#compact`? Or is using `Array#reject` my best bet?

I haven't seen the "empty" equivalent of `#compact`, if there is one. But maybe I'm just overlooking it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes there is!

```
array.reject &:empty?
```

However, as [scarver2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307308/scarver2) and [Hoang Le](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2526476/hoang-le) explained, this will fail with a [`NoMethodError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html) if the array contains `nil`.

---

If you are using [Rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/) or [Active Support](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/), you can safely write:

```
array.reject &:blank?
```

There will be no error since all objects respond to [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F), [including `nil`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-blank-3F).

There is also another way to do it, as suggested by [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short):

```
array.select &:present?
```

It seems [`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) is implemented in terms of `blank?` so both are appropriate.

Comment: I suppose you could also `array.select(&:present?)` in Rails if that read better.

Comment: Good point; for some reason I usually only think to use `&` when I'm doing `Array#map`.

Comment: @muistooshort Great idea with `select(&:present?)` This will return an empty array if all elements are blank. The `reject` method was returning `nil` causing successive methods like `join` or `map` to fail.

Comment: Yup, I think `array.select(&:present?)` is the best solution. Btw, `array.reject &:empty?` can raise error when the array contains a `nil` object then it is not good.

Answer (score 9):

As of Rails 6.1.3.1, you have [`compact_blank`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/Enumerable/compact_blank):

```rb
array = ["a", "", nil, false, [], {}]
array.compact_blank
#=> ["a"]
```

As it's defined on `Enumerable`, you may also use it on hashes.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Rails 6.1 now has support for `compact_blank`

[Docs](https://glaucocustodio.medium.com/rails-6-1-adds-compact-blank-b6f3ecdedd8d)

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important details from the link provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are in a pure ruby project, don't have Active Support (or Rails) and are looking for a copy and paste solution that does not fail on nil. This will help you.

```rb
['', nil, 'foobar'].reject { |i| i.nil? || i.empty? }
```

Or, in case you don't care about looping over the array twice

```rb
['', nil, 'foobar'].compact.reject(&:empty?)
```